# Why settings.default.json file is neglected during install?

Tags: installation, i18n, aegir, l10n

Since CiviCRM 5.23, one can [set a custom L10n/I18n resource directory](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/issues/30). Using this feature with Aegir and Drupal 7 profiles, this setting almost works: CiviCRM sites install with selected language, using the Drupal and CiviCRM language files (.po/.mo) located now at `profiles/myprofile/translations/`.

Missing piece is that the `settings.default.json` file of CiviCRM l10n settings is not picked up during install, so its settings are neglected. The file is at `civicrm/l10n/hu_HU`, next to the .po files.

Is it a bug or am I missing something in my Aegir settings?

Comment: You might want to ask at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/issues/1 since there's a comment there that it may or may not be broken by the new l10n path setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Add a `define('CIVICRM_L10N_BASEDIR', '/var/aegir/platforms/YOUR-PATH');` statement to `platform.settings.php` file of Aegir (see: [Altering Aegir's Behaviours](https://docs.aegirproject.org/extend/altering-behaviours/#customizing-settingsphp)), to set an environmental variable for CiviCRM, to locate the exact place of its l10n files. More info on `CIVICRM_L10N_BASEDIR` [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/issues/30) and [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/issues/39).
2. Correct the line breaks of the example [settings.default.json](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/Default-Language-Settings), otherwise it's not being read as JSON file. The `address_format` and `mailing_format` should be one line, and `\n` have to be added when line break is required. See [MR](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/merge_requests/4).